# CSS grid, place item on new row in column empty on previous row

Tags: css, css-grid

Let's say I have a grid with 2 columns and an unknown number of items. something like:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.new-row {
    grid-column-start: 1;
}

.new-row.col-2 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    */ Now what ??? /*
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <!-- unknown number of items here -->
    <div class="new-row">Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div class="new-row">Column 1</div>
    <div class="new-row col-2">Column 2</div>
    <!-- unknown number of items here -->
</div>
```

At some point I want to have an item in column 1, followed by an item in column 2, but on the next row. Like:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| Column 1 |  |
|  | Column 2 |

I don't know how many items will come before or after, so I can't just put the appropriate number in `grid-row-start`.

I can't alter the HTML, and I can't use JavaScript.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Without knowing the number of items this is not possible. That said, you could just make your "new row" element 2 fr wide...should have the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the whole width and consider padding or margin to push the element into the second column:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.new-row {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.new-row.col-2 {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  margin-left:50%; /* push to second column */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <!-- unknown number of items here -->
  <div class="new-row">Column 1</div>
  <div>Column 2</div>
  <div class="new-row">Column 1</div>
  <div class="new-row col-2">Column 2</div>
  <!-- unknown number of items here -->
</div>
```